# Why is the isometry group of a closed negatively curved manifold finite?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

Why is the isometry group of a closed negatively curved manifold finite?

If the isometry group is infinite, then it must have a subgroup that is isomorphic to $S^1$, but how do I take advantage of this fact?

Comment: What do you mean by "isotropy group" exactly?  Do you mean "isometry group" instead?  These are different things.

Comment: Can you please say why the fact the isometry group is infinite implies it has a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1$? I know the isometry group is a always a Lie group, but is it true that every Lie group of positive dimension has a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the isotropy group had a subgroup isomorphic to $S^1$, then we would have a continuous family of isometries, which we can differentiate to get a (non-zero) Killing vector field $X$ on the manifold. This is very advantageous - we have now converted our airy-fairy information about the symmetry group into a concrete geometric object. In particular, we can now use the Bochner formula for Killing fields:

> If $X$ is a Killing field, then the function $f = \frac12|X|^2$ satisfies $$\Delta f = |\nabla X|^2 - {\rm Ric}(X,X).$$
>
> [Petersen, *Riemannian Geometry 2ed.*, Prop 29]

Since we are assuming negative curvature and $X$ is not identically zero, this implies that $\Delta f$ is non-negative everywhere and positive somewhere, which contradicts the fact that any smooth function on a compact manifold satisfies $\int \Delta f = 0$.

Comment: Are there more elementary approaches? I have no knowledge of the killing form. My knowledge is basically limited to Do Carmo.

Comment: @zach: not that I know of. Killing fields are not difficult to understand (at least to the extent necessary to answer this question)  - for example do Carmo asks you to derive the Killing equation $g(\nabla_Y X, Z) + g(\nabla_Z X, Y) = 0$ from a continuous family of isometries in the exercises of Chapter 3. To get the Bochner formula you just need this equation along with the definition of $\nabla$ and curvature.

Comment: @zach: Killing fields (which are a type of vector field encountered in differential geometry) are completely different from the Killing form (which is a bilinear form encountered in the theory of Lie algebras).