# A closed manifold of negative Ricci curvature has no conformal vector fields

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, curvature, symmetry, conformal-geometry

I am trying to find a reference for the following claim, which is probably well-known:

> Let $M$ be a closed manifold of dimension $\ge 3$, with negative Ricci curvature. Then every **conformal** vector field of $M$ is zero.

Any help would be appreciated.

The isometric case follows from [Bochner's formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2220082/why-is-the-isometry-group-of-a-closed-negatively-curved-manifold-finite).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Theorem 1 of Yano's [On Harmonic and Killing Vector Fields](https://doi.org/10.2307/1969418).